# What does " :\- " match?

Tags: perl

I have the following regex:

```
[\s:\-]
```

How do I match the `:\-`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your character class has just three components: a space type character (`\s`), a colon (`:`) or a minus (`-`). That way you will only match one appearance of one of those three options.

What you are looking for is a regex like `/\s:\-/` without the brackets (`[]`).

Comment: Note: the backslash in `\-` is unnecessary because the hyphen appears at the end of the character class and so [can't be part of a range](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Character-Ranges).

Comment: *"just one character out of three possible"* except that `\s` is a character class by itself which matches six ASCII characters and a lot more from Unicode

Comment: @Borodin I didn't know how to put it correctly in words. You are completely right. Would it be better _out of three possibilities_? In my defence I wrote that `\s` is a space _type_ character, implying a set.

Comment: @eballes: I apologize for forgetting that English may not be your first language. I would say something like *"your character class has just three components"*. Does that help?

Answer (score 5):

[YAPE::Regex::Explain](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAPE::Regex::Explain)

The regular expression:

```
(?-imsx:[\s:\-])

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\s:\-]                  any character of: whitespace (\n, \r, \t,
                           \f, and " "), ':', '\-'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```